# helm reset: Error: OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When doing a `helm reset` I get:

```
helm reset
Error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have same problem, have you solve it?

Comment: Check you can connect to your apiserver.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2464) on GitHub looks pretty close to your case.

The solution provided by [fossxplorer](https://github.com/fossxplorer)  and improved by [johnhamelink](https://github.com/johnhamelink)  is to set `automountServiceAccountToken` parameter to  "`true`" in the `tiller` deployment:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system patch deployment tiller-deploy -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"automountServiceAccountToken": true}}}}'
```

If after that you have the following error:

> Error: configmaps is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list configmaps in
>   the namespace "kube-system"

you should create `ClusterRoleBinding` for service account `kube-system:default`

```
$ kubectl --namespace=kube-system create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
```

I recommend to create separate service account and select it during `Helm` initialization:

```
$ kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
$ helm init --service-account tiller
```

If you want secure `Helm` installation please follow [the manual](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#best-practices-for-securing-helm-and-tiller).

Comment: Setting `automountServiceAccountToken` to `true` might fix the `connection refused` issue, but not the `dial timeout` issue, which indicates network issues of some sorts.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Could you tell me how to solved this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @xavierzhao I stopped using deployed Tiller and now I use local Tiller with my k8s config/account and I forgot about all that madness. https://helm.sh/docs/install/#running-tiller-locally

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and finally solved the problem by change the network configuration of Calico, change the network to: 172.16.0.0/16 both in Calico deployment and Kubeadm init configuration file, not sure why the default network (192.168.0.0/16) not work, and my local network is 192.168.200.0, hope this can help who has same promblem.